# Specify local IP address in net.DialTCP throwing error bind: address already in use

Tags: go, tcp

Written one TCP client which is used to create 10 TCP concurrent connections(holding for logger time) and enable only 10 ephemeral ports to use(49001 - 49010 ip_local_port_range file).

```
func createConnection(c int, desAddr, desPort string) (brokerCon net.Conn, err error) {
    localips := GetLocalIP()
    maxRetry := len(localips)
    retry := 0
    for retry < maxRetry {
        lIPPort := fmt.Sprintf("%s:0", strings.Split(localips[retry].String(), "/")[0])
        fmt.Println("\n---", lIPPort)
        laddr, lerr := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", lIPPort)
        if lerr != nil {
            fmt.Println("Getting Error ResolveTCPAddr for local ", lerr)
        }
        raddr, rerr := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", desAddr+desPort)
        if rerr != nil {
            fmt.Println("Getting Error ResolveTCPAddr for local ", rerr)
        }

        brokerCon, err = net.DialTCP("tcp", laddr, raddr)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to connect connetion %d , %d retrying with seconday IP, err:\n",
                c, retry, err)
            retry = retry + 1
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            continue

        } else {
            //fmt.Println("successfull ")
            break
        }
    }
    return
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

It's able to create 10 connections if the laddr value is **nil** on the DialTCP method. DialTCP is able to use 49009 and 49007 port which is already used by some different destination(as because A TCP connection is determined by a 5-tuple: **[local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port, protocol]** ).

```
sudo netstat -anpl --tcp --udp | grep 490 
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49005       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49010       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49008       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49009       XXX.XXX.XXX.X44:443     ESTABLISHED 3250/XXXX          
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49006       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49002       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49004       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49001       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49007       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49003       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49007       XXX.XXX.XXX.X29:443        ESTABLISHED 2806/XXXX 
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49009       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 23408/client
```

**Scenario 2:**

If I Pass local IP details(10.50.1.245) with 0 port, it's able to create only 8 connections and throwing  **bind: address already in use** for the remaining 2 connections. if the local address is not nil why dialTCP is not able to use 49005 and 49007 port which is already used by some different destination.

```
sudo netstat -anpl --tcp --udp | grep 490 
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49010       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49005       XXX.XXX.XXX.X66:443        ESTABLISHED 2510/XXX 
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49008       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49005       XXX.XXX.XXX.X44:443     ESTABLISHED 3250/XXX         
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49006       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49002       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49004       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49001       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49003       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client        
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49007       XXX.XXX.XXX.X29:443        ESTABLISHED 2806/XXX 
tcp        0      0 10.50.1.245:49009       10.50.1.41:9999         ESTABLISHED 25841/client
```

Comment: It turns out the behavior of `connect()` is fairly jerky  over the space of all options and OS, and you will run into weird garbage like this.  See some of the comments in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go and friends for examples of the Go codebase trying to work around stuff like this.  (Linux blindly round-robin assigns laddrs, in this case)  99% of the time you can ignore the weirdness.   If you want to be absolutely sure, `bind()` before connect (impossible in Go's net public interface, sadly) no avoid  SO_REUSEADDR (annoying and impractical, sadly).